# cx_freeze crea exe pero no guarda datos en docx ni xlsx

Tags: python, pyqt

He escrito una aplicación sencilla con `PyQt4` que realiza unos cálculos. Con cuatro `pushButtons` guardo los datos, los recupero, los guardo en formato `docx` y `xlsx` para la documentación del proyecto y que pueda acceder a ellos un tercero.

Para crear los ficheros `docx` y `xlsx` uso `python-docx` y `XlsxWriter`, para ello creo unos módulos en la carpeta `scripts`.

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

```
classes/  # Clases comunes con otros proyectos.
    |
    |
miproyecto/
    |--__init__.py
    |--miproyecto.pyw
    |--setup.py  # Convierte a exe con cx_Freeze.
    |
    |--icon/  # Iconos del proyecto.
    |
    |--qtdesigner/
    |    |--__init__.py
    |    |--miproyecto.ui
    |    |--miproyecto.py
    |
    |--scripts/
         |--__init__.py
         |--py2docx.py  # Exporta datos a docx.
         |--py2xlsx.py  # Exporta datos a xlsx.
```

Dentro de `miproyecto.pyw` llamo a los diferentes módulos de la siguietne manera:

```
from classes.FEM_2131_2132.chapter_2.loads_0_0_170808 import AdditionalLoads
from qtdesigner.miproyecto import *
from scripts.py2xlsx import py2xlsx
from scripts.py2docx import py2docx
```

`py2xlsx` y `py2docx` son funciones definidas dentro de `py2xlsx.py` y `py2docx.py` que crean los correspondientes ficheros.

Los ficheros `docx` y `xlsx` se guardan en `miproyecto.pyw` de la siguiente manera:

```
    # Export to docx.

    def export_docx(self):    
        name_docx = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save docx', '', '*.docx;; All Files (*.*)')    
        name_py = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-4]    
        data = self.data()    
        py2docx(name_docx, name_py, *data)

    # Export to xlsx.

    def export_xlsx(self):    
        name_xlsx = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save xlsx', '', '*.xlsx;; All Files (*.*)')    
        name_py = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-4]    
        data = self.data()    
        data_temp1 = [d.split('\n') for d in data]  # Get rid of '\n' between fields.
        data_temp2 = []
        for d in data_temp1:
            data_temp2 = data_temp2 + d
        data = data_temp2    
        py2xlsx(name_xlsx, name_py, *data)
```

El script `setup.py` contiene lo siguiente:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

excludes = ['tkinter']
packages = ['os', 'docx', 'lxml']

build_exe_options = {
    'excludes': excludes,
    'packages': packages
    }

exe = Executable(
    script='miproyecto.pyw',
    base='Win32GUI',
    targetName='miproyecto.exe',
    icon='.\icon\Air.ico'
    )

setup(
    name='miproyecto',
    version='0',
    description='Wind action according to FEM 2131/2132',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[exe]
    )
```

Cuando ejecuto `Python` la aplicación funciona perfectamente.

Cuando ejecuto el `setup` mediante `python setup.py build` crea la carpeta `build` con el ejectuable. Cuando lo lanzo, el programa funciona, cálcula los datos, los guarda, los lee de nuevo, cuando le doy a los botones de guardar en docx o xlsx, se abre la ventana de guardar, pero no se guardan los ficheros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque introduzca el nombre y presione sobre guardar no se guarda nada.

Como al ejecutar `Python` funciona todo y al crear el ejecutable con `cx_Freeze` no da mensaje de error y se crea la carpeta con los ficheros, aparentemente todo normal, no sé cómo atacar este problema.

**Editado el 21-09-2017**

Siguiendo el consejo de @FJSevilla he introducido un `logging` en el método `export_docx()`:

```
def export_docx(self):

    logging.debug('Abre ventana para guardar docx.')
    name_docx = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save docx', '', '*.docx;; All Files (*.*)')

    logging.debug('Registra nombre de la aplicación.')
    name_py = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-4]

    logging.debug('Traspasa datos.')
    data = self.data()

    logging.debug('Ejecuta la función py2docx() y guarda fichero docx.')
    py2docx(name_docx, name_py, *data)
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa desde la terminal de `Python` obtengo el siguiente log:

```
2017-09-21 18:47:43,660 : DEBUG : Abre ventana para guardar docx.
2017-09-21 18:47:51,189 : DEBUG : Registra nombre de la aplicación.
2017-09-21 18:47:51,189 : DEBUG : Traspasa datos.
2017-09-21 18:47:51,189 : DEBUG : Ejecuta la función py2docx() y guarda fichero docx.
```

Pero al lanzar el `setup` de `cx_Frezze` obtengo el siguiente:

```
2017-09-21 18:49:44,306 : DEBUG : Abre ventana para guardar docx.
2017-09-21 18:49:52,942 : DEBUG : Registra nombre de la aplicación.
```

Comment: Por lo que comentas parece que el problema está en  `py2docx` y `py2xlsx`. Yo implementaría un [loggin](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) apropiado en esos dos módulos a ver donde falla exactamente. Sería muy bueno que crearas un ejemplo mínimo con solo estos módulos, sin GUI. Simplemente que al ejecutar cree dos documentos en una ruta válida con algunos datos y que uses cx_freeze sobre el, podrías publicar el código de este ejemplo sin exponer todo tu proyecto para ver si podemos reproducirlo nosotros. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo de crear un ejemplo sencillo ya lo hice y funciona sin problema.

Comment: He vuelto ha crear un ejemplo sencillo, esta vez empleando la misma estructura del proyecto y simplificando el código y el resultado es el mismo, el ejecutable funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si con ejemplos simples te genera los archivos sin problemas podemos descartar que sea un problema de compatibilidad entre cx-freeze y las librerias externas usadas. Al correr el proyecto de forma natural con el interprete tampoco hay problemas... Y sin errores... genial, uno de esos bug fantasmas... Intenta crear el exe eliminando la opción `base='Win32GUI'`, del setup para que se abra la consola al ejecutar y observa si se retorna alguna excepción cuando falla la app. Si no, creo que como te comente deberías establecer un loggin adecuado a ver si puedes aislar la linea en la que falla...

Answer (score 0):

Tras hacer el siguiente `logging` más depurado en el método `export_doc`

```
def export_docx(self):

    logging.info('Abre ventana para guardar docx.')
    name_docx = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save docx', '', '*.docx;; All Files (*.*)')
    logging.info('Abierta ventana para guardar docx.')

    logging.info('Registra nombre de la aplicación.')
    name_py = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-4]
    logging.info('Registrado nombre de la aplicación.')

    logging.info('Traspasa datos.')
    data = self.data()
    logging.info('Traspasados datos.')

    logging.info('Ejecuta la función py2docx()')
    py2docx(name_docx, name_py, *data)
    logging.info('Ejecutada la función py2docx()')
```

obtuve el siguiente resultado:

```
2017-09-30 18:51:23,811 : INFO : Abre ventana para guardar docx.
2017-09-30 18:51:30,038 : INFO : Abierta ventana para guardar docx.
2017-09-30 18:51:30,039 : INFO : Registra nombre de la aplicación.
```

Por tanto el código problemático era:

```
name_py = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-4]
```

que pretende que en el documento docx aparezca el nombre de la aplicación sin la extensión. Esta pista me llevó al siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937695/python-cx-freeze-name-file-is-not-defined). Al sustituirlo por el siguiente código el problema ha quedado resuelto.

```
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # frozen
        name_py = os.path.basename(sys.executable)[:-4]
    else:
        # unfrozen
        name_py = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))[:-4]
```